# what is the best way to pass variables from a node.js file to another?

Tags: node.js, command-line-arguments, ipc

I made researches and i did not find what i want.

I have for example a Node.js file with the code:

```
var pseudo = req.body.pseudo;
var activation_link = generate_random_key();
message = ?
send_mail(destinataire, "subject", message);
```

and another independant node.js file that have:

```
var message = Hello {{pseudo}}. Welcome to my website. The link of activation to activate your account is: {{activation_link}}
```

As you can guess, I want to pass pseudo variable from the first file to the second file, ans also pass the message variable from file2 to file1.

Question: what is the best proper wat to do that ?

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

The [process.argv](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) should help you.
And when you're done with that, for interprocess comunication [this will help you](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options).